# gravity pdf save to server file

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I try to save a copy of PDF files to a folder on the server.
There is a tutorial of gravitypdf at the following [link](https://gravitypdf.com/documentation/v4/gfpdf_post_save_pdf/):
https://gravitypdf.com/documentation/v4/gfpdf_post_save_pdf/
Unfortunately I can not make it work.
Apparently I did not understand exactly where to put the code and how to adjust the parameters

Would appreciate help
Thanks

EDIT

```
add_action( 'gfpdf_post_save_pdf', function( $pdf_path, $filename, $settings, $entry, $form ) {
    /* Only move PDFs from form #2 / 
    if ( '2' == $form['id'] ) { 
        /* The directory we want to copy our PDF to */ 
        $copy_to_dir = ABSPATH . 'PDFs/'; 
        /* Ensure we get a unique filename for the directory we are copying to */ 
        $filename = wp_unique_filename( $copy_to_dir, $filename ); 
        /* Copy the PDF to the new directory */ 
        copy( $pdf_path, $copy_to_dir . $filename ); 
    } 
}, 10, 5 );
```

Comment: please include your code in the question

Comment: add_action( 'gfpdf_post_save_pdf', function( $pdf_path, $filename, $settings, $entry, $form ) {

    /* Only move PDFs from form #2 */
    if ( '2' == $form['id'] ) {
        /* The directory we want to copy our PDF to */
        $copy_to_dir = ABSPATH . 'PDFs/';

        /* Ensure we get a unique filename for the directory we are copying to */
        $filename = wp_unique_filename( $copy_to_dir, $filename );

        /* Copy the PDF to the new directory */
        copy( $pdf_path, $copy_to_dir . $filename );
    }

}, 10, 5 );

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code to `functions.php`.

Also, you have an error in the code, you need to comment correctly. Change `/* Only move PDFs from form #2 /` to `/* Only move PDFs from form #2 */`

Comment: 10 is the priority so it overwrites another function and 5 is the arguments, as you can see there are 5 variables parsed to the function. If you set this to 4, then it would ignore the 5th variable.